# Standard deviation of inverse of normal distribution

Tags: statistics

A number of people complete a race, each with a race time $t$, which may be assumed to be normally distributed with mean race time $t_m$ and standard deviation $SD$. The length of the track is $L$.

Suppose I wanted to know about the speed of the racers $s=L/t$. The average speed is obviously $s_m=L/t_m$. But how would I go about figuring out or estimating the standard deviation of the speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is not obvious that the average speed is $L/t_m$.  In fact, this is not mathematically true, since in general $$\operatorname{E}[1/X] \ne 1/\operatorname{E}[X].$$

To see why, suppose you realize a sample of race times among $n$ riders:  $$\boldsymbol T = (t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n).$$  Now, their average time is $\bar T = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n t_i$.  For a track $L = 1$ (the units are irrelevant), the race speeds observed are $$\boldsymbol S = (s_1, s_2, \ldots s_n) = (1/t_1, 1/t_2, \ldots, 1/t_n).$$  But this has the average value $$\bar S = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n s_i = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{t_i} \ne \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n t_i} = \frac{1}{\bar T}.$$  In fact, this inequality is especially apparent if the number of riders is small; e.g., if $n = 2$, it is quite apparent that $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{t_1} + \frac{1}{t_2}\right) \ne \frac{2}{t_1 + t_2}.$$  Equality is attained if and only if $t_1 = t_2$.  Suffice it to say that the correct way to calculate average speed is to take the observed sample of the race times, compute $s_i = L/t_i$ for each rider $i$, and take the arithmetic mean.

For the sample standard deviation, you'd do the same thing.

However, from a theoretical standpoint, it is immediately clear that since $$\operatorname{E}[1/Z] = \int_{z=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{z} e^{-z^2/2} \, dz$$ is unbounded for a standard normal random variable $Z$, you have no hope of obtaining a closed-form expression for the expectation (let alone standard deviation) of the reciprocal of a normal random variable with general parameters $\mu$, $\sigma$.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, it doesn't have one.

To get the standard deviation you first need the mean. You know that the density of the normal is $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(t-\mu)^2}$$ so to get the mean of $v = L/t$ we just take $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{L}{t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(t-\mu)^2}dt.$$

Uh oh... The integrand has a $1/t$ in it and that diverges at the origin in such a way that the integral doesn't exist.

So it doesn't have a mean.

And to get the variance you'd need to take the second moment, which will have a $1/t^2$ divergence at the origin, which is even worse. In general some random variables don't have higher moments. And some, like this one, have none.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1 indicates there is not a closed form solution, which is true enough.
Answer 2 seems to say that there is no average speed, which is absurd. Of course you can determine an average speed. Again, there is just not a precise closed form solution based on only the mean and standard deviation of the original variables.

But we have approximations.

In the real world, with a large number of runners, a normal distribution of finishing times and a standard deviation of times $sT$ which is much smaller than the mean race time $Tm$, then the mean velocity $Vm$ can be indeed be approximated by $L/Tm$ and the standard deviation $sV$ of the velocity can be approximated as:

$$sV = \frac{L\cdot sT}{Tm^2}$$